Detect active local ip programmatically in C/C++
I'm looking for a way to detect the active local IP address in a system (Windows and Linux). With the word "active", I mean the IP currently used to exchange data in the network.
There are various ways to get the local IP(s), like using getaddrinfo() or getifaddrs(), but these functions return the list of current IP addresses available and my problem is to know which of them is the currently active IP being used.
To give an example - if my system is connected to an Ethernet network, the Ethernet device will have an assigned IP. Now, if I switch to a Wifi network, the Wifi device will have its own IP too, but the IP of the Ethernet will remain. This has as a consequence that scanning for a local IP will return two valid IPs, but only one of them is used to communicate (in this example, the Wifi IP).
Is there a (programmatically) way to find the active one, using C or C++? Please note I'm in a network without Internet access, so it is not possible to connect to some remote web address to check the local source IP.

but only one of them is used to communicate not really, both can be used as well, it depends on routing

In a common situation, however, only one of them are the active one

Pick either "C" or "C++", that said neither language has native support for networking. So you will have to find some kind of library

I know but C are the native language used for the Windows/Linux API. I'm looking for a code solution. If exist a library doing the job in any case will use the C system API to get the result.

"In a common situation, however, only one of them are the active one" That is an incorrect statement. Either is used, based on the routing table in the host. The host will send a packet to the most appropriate interface based on the destination address and its routing table.

My PC has two ethernet interfaces. One is a connection to a network, the other is used with VLANs, and every VLAN also has an address in a network. Depending on the destination, the addressed ethernet interface or one of the VLAN interfaces that uses the other ethernet interface will be used. Absent a match in the routing table, the default route is used. You can see the routing table in your PC, and you could determine from that which path a packet with a specific destination address will use.

@FalsinSoft What I wanted to say is if you use C++ look for a C++ library (you will get all the benefits of RAII and possible C++'s threading models). Using a "C" api from C++ is possible but usually clumsy and more likely to end up with buggy code. So yes really pick one.

Do you have link to some code example or library?

E.g. have a look at Get Local IP-Address using Boost.Asio that link has more hints too

@PepijnKramer from a quick read it seems the library require an external web site that is not my case since I don't have internet available in the network. However I'll do a better check...

VPN, VLAN, docker and others add more local network devices and sometimes many of them. In Linux, /proc/net/dev contains a list of these devices. /proc/net/route reflects the current routing table.

"In a common situation, however, only one of them are the active one" I manage about 15 Linux servers. And all have ≥2 active network devices with ≥2 different IPv4 addresses and different IPv6 addresses.

@Wiimm I know there are cases like server that can have multiple connection but is not my case. My case is the one I described and for what I'm looking for a solution...

Have a look at if_indextoname. It uses struct ifreq ifr; and does ioctl(fd,SIOCGIFNAME,&ifr) Also, SIOCGIFADDR ioctl may help. See man 7 netdevice These work on interfaces. Usually, interface at index 0 is the default/correct one.

@CraigEstey Thank you for the suggestion. This seems a Linux-only solution but if it will work would be a good way to follow to get the same result in Windows also.

@FalsinSoft On Windows, GetAdapatersAddresses() gives you a lot of details about the available IPs, including which IPs belong to which adapters, what the interface indexes are for each adapter, their routing metrics (priorities), etc.

There is nothing wrong with  conditional compilation for either OS, or you can create an abstract base class and provide OS specific implementations (compile the one you need). Also helps with unit testability (since you can inject mocks/stubs that give you a correct or incorrect answer)

You may have use some preprocessor conditionals  and do some #ifdef WINDOWS and select Remy's solution of GetAdapterAddresses and #ifdef __linux__ for ioctl solution

Yes, I know how to do conditional compilation. My problem was to find a corrent way to get the result in both systems. Thank you to all for the help.

It sounds like the actual question being asked is "which interface will be used to communicate with the default router?"

It can be checked with socket connection to find the active IP address in the system.
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create socket.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in serv;
    std::memset(&serv, 0, sizeof(serv));
    serv.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv.sin_port = htons(80);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "8.8.8.8", &serv.sin_addr);

    int err = connect(sock, (const struct sockaddr *)&serv, sizeof(serv));
    if (err < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Connection failed.\n";
        close(sock);
        return 1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in name;
    socklen_t namelen = sizeof(name);
    err = getsockname(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&name, &namelen);
    if (err < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "getsockname() failed.\n";
        close(sock);
        return 1;
    }

    char buffer[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &name.sin_addr, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    std::cout << "Active local IP address: " << buffer << std::endl;

    close(sock);
    return 0;
}

A connection request is sent to the external IP (Google DNS). In fact, our goal in this section is not to send a request to the network. The goal of this section is to determine which IP is used to send a request to the network. In this section, the absence of internet is not a problem. This allows us to determine which local network interface (e.g. Ethernet or Wi-Fi) is active.
NOTE: This code is for linux environment
NOTE: Here the IP address of the Google DNS server is 8.8.8.8 and the HTTP port is 80. This IP is not intended to be a real connection; it is simply to find out what the local IP address is by trying to connect to this address.

This solution require to connect to Google DNS "8.8.8.8". I can not exit from local network.

Last line of OP's question: "Please note I'm in a network without internet access than is not possible to connect to some remote web address to check the local source ip". So, trying to access 8.8.8.8 (google?) isn't possible.

@FalsinSoft this code is using a UDP socket. There is no connection to the external server.  It is merely setting the destination IP statically on the UDP socket, and then asking which local IP would be used to send packets to that IP

@RemyLebeau so the connect() function will not fail in case of destination host unreachable? I'll give it a try. Thank you

@FalsinSoft
There is no need for internet for this code to work. The important part is that there is a device that sends IP to the device in this code. Turn off the internet and try the code, it will work

@FalsinSoft that is correct. UDP is connection-less, so connect() for UDP does not communicate with the remote host, it is just a static assignment locally. Only sendto() and recvfrom() do any communicating.

@CraigEstey Please first try the code on a network where there is no internet, it will work, you just need a device that will assign an IP to your device.

but if that's so you can open a socket to listen on and do an udp broadcast and check where you receive the packet from?

@PepijnKramer Yes, you can find the active IP address by sending a broadcast over UDP and checking which interface the packet is received from. However, this is more complex and involves more lines of code. Honestly, that was the first idea that came to my mind, but it makes sense in the situation you mentioned. But won't the firewall cause problems?

@serkan I can confirm your solution work very very well. Simply and efficient can work on Windows also with minimal changes. Thank you very much for the help, you made my day!

This is a solution using local udp broadcast to get the active ip address. It is tested on MacBook, but it also should work on Linux.
Broadcast receiver:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
//#include <linux/in.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

#define BCAST_MSG "Are you there"
#define BCAST_MSG_ACK "Yes"
#define PORT 9898

int main() {
struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
unsigned int addr_len;
int nbytes;
int sock, ret;
fd_set readfd;
char pktbuf[1400];

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if (sock < 0) {
    perror("sock error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

addr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

memset((void*)&server_addr, 0, addr_len);
server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
server_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

ret = bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, addr_len);
if (ret < 0) {
    perror("bind error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
while (1) {
    FD_ZERO(&readfd);
    FD_SET(sock, &readfd);

    ret = select(sock+1, &readfd, NULL, NULL, 0);
    if (ret > 0) {
    if (FD_ISSET(sock, &readfd)) {
        nbytes = recvfrom(sock, pktbuf, 1024, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &addr_len);
        if (strstr(pktbuf, BCAST_MSG)) {
        printf("\nReceived broadcast msg \"%s\" from IP: %s, Port: %d\n",
            pktbuf,
            inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
            memcpy(pktbuf, BCAST_MSG_ACK, strlen(BCAST_MSG_ACK)+1);
            nbytes = sendto(sock, pktbuf, strlen(pktbuf), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, addr_len);
        }
    }
    }
}
return 0;
}

Broadcast sender:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
//#include <linux/in.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>

#define BCAST_MSG "Are you there"
#define BCAST_MSG_ACK "Yes"
#define PORT 9898

int main() {
    struct sockaddr_in broadcast_addr;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    unsigned int addr_len;
    int nbytes;
    int sock, i, ret, enable = 1;;
    fd_set readfd;
    char pktbuf[1400];

    struct hostent *thisHost = NULL;
    char ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    char hostbuffer[256];
    //struct sockaddr_in addr = {};
    struct in_addr **addr_list;

    // to retrieve hostname
    if (!gethostname(hostbuffer, sizeof(hostbuffer)))
        thisHost = gethostbyname(hostbuffer);
    addr_list = (struct in_addr **)thisHost->h_addr_list;
    printf("Local host IP address(es):\n"); 
    for (int i = 0; addr_list[i] != NULL; i++) {
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, (struct in_addr *)addr_list[i], ip, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
        printf("\taddress %d: %s\n", i+1, ip); //inet_ntoa(*addr_list[i]));
    }
    
    // to find local active IP address:
    bool found = false;
    addr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    memset((void*)&broadcast_addr, 0, addr_len);
    broadcast_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    broadcast_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_BROADCAST);
    broadcast_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0) {
        perror("sock error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ret = setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (char*)&enable, sizeof(enable));
    if (ret == -1) {
        perror("setsockopt error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
        ret = sendto(sock, BCAST_MSG, strlen(BCAST_MSG), 0, 
                    (struct sockaddr*) &broadcast_addr, addr_len);

        FD_ZERO(&readfd);
        FD_SET(sock, &readfd);

        ret = select(sock + 1, &readfd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        if (ret > 0) {
            if (FD_ISSET(sock, &readfd)) {
                nbytes = recvfrom(sock, pktbuf, 1024, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, &addr_len);
                if (strstr(pktbuf, BCAST_MSG_ACK) && !found) {
                    printf("\nFound Active IP Address: %s, Port: %d\n", 
                            inet_ntoa(server_addr.sin_addr),
                            htons(server_addr.sin_port));
                    found = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //more details about each network interface:
    printf("\nMore detials about local network interfaces:\n"); 

    struct ifaddrs *addrs=NULL, *tmp=NULL;
    int family, s;
    char host[NI_MAXHOST];
    if (!getifaddrs(&addrs))
        tmp = addrs;
    while (tmp)
    {
        if (tmp->ifa_addr && tmp->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET)
        {
            struct sockaddr_in *pAddr = (struct sockaddr_in *)tmp->ifa_addr;
            printf("\t%s: %s\n", tmp->ifa_name, inet_ntoa(pAddr->sin_addr));
        }
        tmp = tmp->ifa_next;
    }

    // go through linked list, maintaining head pointer, free list later. 
    for (struct ifaddrs *ifa = addrs; ifa != NULL;
        ifa = ifa->ifa_next) {
        if (ifa->ifa_addr == NULL)
            continue;
        family = ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family;
        // print interface name and family 
        // including symbolic form of the latter for the common families
        printf("\t%-8s %s (%d)\n",
                ifa->ifa_name,
                (family == AF_INET) ? "AF_INET" :
                (family == AF_INET6) ? "AF_INET6" : "???",
                family);

        //for an AF_INET* interface address, display the address
        if (family == AF_INET || family == AF_INET6) {
            s = getnameinfo(ifa->ifa_addr,
                (family == AF_INET) ? sizeof(struct sockaddr_in) : sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6),
                host, NI_MAXHOST, NULL, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST);
            if (s != 0) {
                printf("getnameinfo() failed: %s\n", gai_strerror(s));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            printf("\taddress: <%s>\n", host);
        }
    }
    freeifaddrs(addrs);
    return 0;
}

You run receiver code first, then run udp sender. The output is like this below:
Local host IP address(es):
    address 1: 127.0.0.1
    address 2: 192.168.0.101

Found Active IP Address: 192.168.0.101, Port: 9898

More detials about local network interfaces:
        lo0: 127.0.0.1
        en0: 192.168.0.101
        lo0      ??? (18)
        lo0      AF_INET (2)
        address: <127.0.0.1>
        lo0      AF_INET6 (30)
        address: <::1>
        lo0      AF_INET6 (30)
        address: <fe80::1%lo0>
        gif0     ??? (18)
        stf0     ??? (18)
        en0      ??? (18)
        en0      AF_INET6 (30)
        address: <fe80::1482:95d2:1bed:a64c%en0>
        en0      AF_INET (2)
        address: <192.168.0.101>
        en1      ??? (18)
        en2      ??? (18)
        bridge0  ??? (18)
        p2p0     ??? (18)
        awdl0    ??? (18)
        awdl0    AF_INET6 (30)
        address: <fe80::c2d:38ff:fe3d:f9bf%awdl0>
        llw0     ??? (18)
        llw0     AF_INET6 (30)
        address: <fe80::c2d:38ff:fe3d:f9bf%llw0>
        utun0    ??? (18)
        utun0    AF_INET6 (30)
        address: <fe80::4589:48f4:a286:dc51%utun0>
        utun1    ??? (18)
        utun1    AF_INET6 (30)
        address: <fe80::a428:2512:848b:f44d%utun1>
        utun2    ??? (18)
        utun2    AF_INET6 (30)
        address: <fe80::ce81:b1c:bd2c:69e%utun2>


or else
You can use nMap or ZENMAP
to find active I.p in your subnet in matter of seconds
Also efficient

OP wants to do this programmatically.
